# How do I set up a TailwindCSS build to output both a purged version and non-purged version?

Tags: tailwind-css

I set up TailwindCSS in a pretty typical way using the docs they provide. In my package.json, I have this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "postcss css/tailwind.css -o public/build/tailwind.css"
  },
```

And in my tailwind.config.js, I have this:

```
  purge: {
    // enabled: true,
    // mode: 'layers',
    // layers: ['base', 'components', 'utilities'],
    // content: ['./sandbox/*.html', './home.ascx', './default.ascx', './partials/*.ascx', '../../../0/2sxc/Content/*.cshtml', '../../Containers/DNN-TailwindCSS/*.ascx'],
```

In my current workflow, I build my websites with the purge commented out so it outputs the whole thing. Then when I'm ready to deploy, I uncomment the purge and build it so it makes the file small by purging out the unused elements.

But I don't want to have to constantly turn the purge on and off when I'm working. I would rather have my npm run build create both the purged version and the full version at the same time but with different file names of course. Perhaps tailwind.css and tailwind.min.css. That way, I can easily swap out the stylesheet when I want to develop.

How do I set it up so npm run build outputs both versions? Or am I think about this the wrong way and should use a different method?

Comment: Couldn't you set the `enabled` param in the `purge` object based on an environment variable, then pass it when building the CSS?

Comment: How do I do that?